# Sklearn Installation : Trying to acquire the GIL while it is already held

Tags: python, ubuntu, scikit-learn, cython

I am getting the following error when trying to install scikit-learn from the github page after running the command `sudo python setup.py install`

```
Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
blas_opt_info:
blas_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
  NOT AVAILABLE

blis_info:
  libraries blis not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries tatlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib/atlas-base', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_blas_info:
  libraries satlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib/atlas-base', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib/atlas-base', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Found executable /usr/bin/gfortran
customize Gnu95FCompiler
customize Gnu95FCompiler using config
compiling '_configtest.c':

/* This file is generated from numpy/distutils/system_info.py */
void ATL_buildinfo(void);
int main(void) {
  ATL_buildinfo();
  return 0;
}

C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC

compile options: '-c'
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread _configtest.o -L/usr/lib/atlas-base -lf77blas -lcblas -latlas -o _configtest
ATLAS version 3.10.2 built by buildd on Mon Nov 23 23:12:07 UTC 2015:
   UNAME    : Linux lgw01-49 3.19.0-33-generic #38 14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:17:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
   INSTFLG  : -1 0 -a 1 -l 1
   ARCHDEFS : -DATL_OS_Linux -DATL_ARCH_x86SSE2 -DATL_CPUMHZ=2095 -DATL_SSE2 -DATL_SSE1 -DATL_USE64BITS -DATL_GAS_x8664
   F2CDEFS  : -DAdd_ -DF77_INTEGER=int -DStringSunStyle
   CACHEEDGE: 1048576
   F77      : /usr/bin/gfortran, version GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 5.2.1-24ubuntu3) 5.2.1 20151121
   F77FLAGS : -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpmath=sse -O2 -msse2 -fPIC -m64
   SMC      : /usr/bin/gcc, version gcc (Ubuntu 5.2.1-24ubuntu3) 5.2.1 20151121
   SMCFLAGS : -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpmath=sse -O2 -msse2 -fPIC -m64
   SKC      : /usr/bin/gcc, version gcc (Ubuntu 5.2.1-24ubuntu3) 5.2.1 20151121
   SKCFLAGS : -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpmath=sse -O2 -msse2 -fPIC -m64
success!
removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest
  FOUND:
    libraries = ['f77blas', 'cblas', 'atlas', 'f77blas', 'cblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/atlas-base']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.10.2\\""')]
    include_dirs = ['/usr/include/atlas']

  FOUND:
    libraries = ['f77blas', 'cblas', 'atlas', 'f77blas', 'cblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/atlas-base']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.10.2\\""')]
    include_dirs = ['/usr/include/atlas']

Warning: Extension name 'sklearn.metrics/cluster.expected_mutual_info_fast' does not match fully qualified name 'sklearn.metrics.cluster.expected_mutual_info_fast' of 'sklearn/metrics/cluster/expected_mutual_info_fast.pyx'
Compiling sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.pyx because it depends on /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython-0.28a0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd.
Compiling sklearn/cluster/_hierarchical.pyx because it depends on /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython-0.28a0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd.
Compiling sklearn/cluster/_k_means_elkan.pyx because it depends on /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython-0.28a0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd.
Compiling sklearn/cluster/_k_means.pyx because it depends on /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython-0.28a0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd.
Compiling sklearn/datasets/_svmlight_format.pyx because it depends on /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython-0.28a0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd.
Compiling sklearn/decomposition/_online_lda.pyx because it depends on /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython-0.28a0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Includes/numpy/math.pxd.
Compiling sklearn/decomposition/cdnmf_fast.pyx because it depends on /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython-0.28a0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Includes/libc/math.pxd.
Compiling sklearn/ensemble/_gradient_boosting.pyx because it depends on /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython-0.28a0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd.
Compiling sklearn/feature_extraction/_hashing.pyx because it depends on /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython-0.28a0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd.
Compiling sklearn/manifold/_utils.pyx because it depends on /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython-0.28a0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd.
Compiling sklearn/manifold/_barnes_hut_tsne.pyx because it depends on /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython-0.28a0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd.
Compiling sklearn/metrics/pairwise_fast.pyx because it depends on /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython-0.28a0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd.
Compiling sklearn/metrics/cluster/expected_mutual_info_fast.pyx because it depends on /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython-0.28a0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd.
Compiling sklearn/neighbors/ball_tree.pyx because it depends on /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython-0.28a0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd.
Compiling sklearn/neighbors/kd_tree.pyx because it changed.
Compiling sklearn/neighbors/dist_metrics.pyx because it changed.
Compiling sklearn/neighbors/typedefs.pyx because it changed.
Compiling sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx because it changed.
Compiling sklearn/tree/_splitter.pyx because it changed.
Compiling sklearn/tree/_criterion.pyx because it changed.
Compiling sklearn/tree/_utils.pyx because it changed.
Compiling sklearn/svm/libsvm.pyx because it changed.
Compiling sklearn/svm/liblinear.pyx because it changed.
Compiling sklearn/svm/libsvm_sparse.pyx because it changed.
Compiling sklearn/_isotonic.pyx because it depends on /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython-0.28a0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd.
Compiling sklearn/linear_model/cd_fast.pyx because it depends on /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython-0.28a0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd.
Compiling sklearn/linear_model/sgd_fast.pyx because it depends on /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython-0.28a0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Includes/numpy/math.pxd.
Compiling sklearn/linear_model/sag_fast.pyx because it depends on /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython-0.28a0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd.
Compiling sklearn/utils/sparsefuncs_fast.pyx because it changed.
Compiling sklearn/utils/arrayfuncs.pyx because it changed.
Compiling sklearn/utils/murmurhash.pyx because it changed.
Compiling sklearn/utils/lgamma.pyx because it changed.
Compiling sklearn/utils/graph_shortest_path.pyx because it changed.
Compiling sklearn/utils/fast_dict.pyx because it changed.
Compiling sklearn/utils/seq_dataset.pyx because it changed.
Compiling sklearn/utils/weight_vector.pyx because it changed.
Compiling sklearn/utils/_random.pyx because it changed.
Compiling sklearn/utils/_logistic_sigmoid.pyx because it changed.
[ 1/38] Cythonizing sklearn/neighbors/dist_metrics.pyx
warning: TestClass:20:10: 'cpdef_method' redeclared 
warning: TestClass:31:10: 'cpdef_cname_method' redeclared 

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

    cdef inline DTYPE_t dist(self, DTYPE_t* x1, DTYPE_t* x2,
                             ITYPE_t size) except -1 with gil:
        cdef np.ndarray x1arr
        cdef np.ndarray x2arr
        with gil:
            ^
------------------------------------------------------------

sklearn/neighbors/dist_metrics.pyx:1100:13: Trying to acquire the GIL while it is already held.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 269, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 265, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "setup.py", line 135, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('sklearn')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1029, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 998, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 935, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "sklearn/setup.py", line 82, in configuration
    maybe_cythonize_extensions(top_path, config)
  File "/home/kashif/Downloads/scikit-learn-master/sklearn/_build_utils/__init__.py", line 84, in maybe_cythonize_extensions
    config.ext_modules = cythonize(config.ext_modules)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython-0.28a0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1039, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython-0.28a0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1161, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: sklearn/neighbors/dist_metrics.pyx
```

I also tried [this link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9272) but it didn't help.

I have tried updating the cython version and cblas as well. Any help is appreciated. I specifically want to install it from the master-branch to check if a specific bug is fixed or not. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given that this bug seems to be associated with specific Cython versions and specific versions of sklearn, do you want to say _exaxtly_ which versions you are using.

Comment: Errors like these are most probably an issue with latest scikit-learn and should be reported as a bug on its github page.